# Best way with Pandas to find rows with a select duplicate column values and aggregate them

Tags: python, pandas

I've created a function that looks for rows that have a set of column values that are the same. It's ugly though: nested apply functions. Is there a better way to test if `n` number columns have the same value, and if so apply a function to them or add them to a dictionary?

```
#function to add valid polls to dictionary
def j(x,i,cand_name):
        if (x['_pollname'] in valid_polls):
            if (x['_poll'] in valid_elections):
                if(np.isfinite(x[cand_name])):
                    toappenddf = {}
                    toappenddf['candidate'] = str(cand_name)
                    toappenddf['date'] = x['_date']
                    toappenddf['poll'] = x['_pollname']
                    toappenddf['polled'] = x[cand_name]
                    appendc.append(toappenddf)

invalid_cols = ['_poll','_pollname','_date']

# run the function
for val in enumerate(list(df3.columns.values)):
    if (val[1] not in invalid_cols):
        df3.apply(lambda row: j(row,i,val[1]), axis=1)

#create dataframe from results
df0 = pd.DataFrame(appendc)
pollaggregator = []

#create nested for loops
def k(x):
    def h(w,i,xx):
        # see if there's a match along three column values between any two rows
        if ((w.candidate == xx.candidate) & (w.date == xx.date) & (xx.poll != w.poll)):
            appendpoll = {}
            appendpoll = w.tolist()
            pollaggregator.append(appendpoll)
    df0.apply(lambda row: h(row,i,x), axis=1)

    if (len(pollaggregator) > 0):
        appendpoll2 = {}
        appendpoll2 = x.tolist()

df0.apply(k, axis=1)
```

The input data is polling data in a dataframe like this:

```
,candidate,date,poll,polled
0,Biden,2014-12-21 00:00:00,CNN,8.0
1,Biden,2015-01-27 00:00:00,FOX News,17.0
2,Biden,2015-02-15 00:00:00,CNN,14.0
3,Biden,2015-03-02 00:00:00,Quinnipiac,10.0
4,Biden,2015-03-13 00:00:00,CNN/ORC,15.0
5,Biden,2015-03-31 00:00:00,FOX News,12.0
6,Biden,2015-04-24 00:00:00,FOX News,9.0
7,Biden,2015-04-20 00:00:00,CNN/Opinion Research,11.0
8,Biden,2015-04-23 00:00:00,Quinnipiac,10.0
9,Biden,2015-04-24 00:00:00,FOX News,9.0
```

For my purposes, I'm looking to aggregate rows that have the same day value, but different poll name value.

Comment: Example input and output often helps.

Comment: So you unique groupings by day?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes but only according to certain criteria -- e.g., where the poll names are the same but the polling organizations different...

Comment: @Incodeveritas Is it possible to upload a sample file with at least a few hundred lines? For example, a dropbox share link with your csv file.

Comment: So poll and date are equal but polled must be unique? Basically `df.groupby(("date","poll"))` and the unique element from that?

Comment: @JianxunLi  added sample rows.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Ok will try.

Comment: The only pair in your sample that would be grouped are index 6 and 9, `print(df.groupby(("date", "poll")).groups)` is that correct?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Increasing the sample.. the sample is much larger.

Comment: Logic should still be the same, group by the two keys, remove dupes from each group and use those values for your dataframe, also `df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)` would remove all the dupes